# Required file 'alink.dll with IAlink3'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, solution, build-error

I was trying to build a C# solution on my Visual Studio 2008, that is running on a Windows Vista machine, but when I try to build it I'm getting this error:

```
Required file 'alink.dll with IAlink3' could not be found Amigo X
```

"Amigo X" is the name of the solution. What is wrong?

PS: Amigo X is a party that we have here in Brazil at the christmas, it's at the time to gave presents to your family. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a C# 3.0 compiler on a machine which does not have CLR 2.0 **SP1** installed.  Try manually installing 2.0 SP1 and seeing if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Nathan, yes this is definitely wrong.  You cannot use the C# 3.0 compiler on a machine where the 2.0 SP1 patch is applied.  There are updates to the core CLR which the 3.0 compiler relies on.  In particular, it relies on IAlink3 to generate UAC manifest information.

Comment: I'm going to install it, if it solves my problem will accept your answer, but at this  time +1.

Comment: @Nathan, if it doesn't solve the problem please post the version number of alink.dll in directory %WINDIR%\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727 to the question.  That will help in tracking down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem and there is an easy fix.

```
  1. Open project properties.
  2. In the Application tab, find the Manifest dropdown. choose the option 'Create application without a manifest'
  3. Run the application successfully.
```